# OpenGL library missing on mac when compiling software package from source

Tags: xcode, macos, opengl

I'm installing a printed-circuit board layout tool called pcb (I'm using [pcb version 20140316](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pcb/files/pcb/pcb-20140316/).  I'm on a Mac (OS X 10.9 -- Mavericks).  I would prefer to install pcb via homebrew, but there is [currently a problem](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-x11/issues/120) with the homebrew version, so in the meantime, I'm trying to compile pcb from source.  When I run the configure script for pcb, it halts with

```
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for OpenGL/gl.h... yes
checking for OpenGL library... no
configure: error: in `/Users/jbattat/gedaGIT/pcb':
configure: error: OpenGL is required.
```

Web searches suggest that the OpenGL libraries are installed via XCode and the command-line tools.  I have installed Xcode (version 6.2), and I have installed the command-line tools via `xcode-select --install`, which claimed to succeed ("The software was installed").

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
$ xcode-select -v
xcode-select version 2333.
```

However the OpenGL library is still not found by the pcb configure script.

I'm not sure how to proceed... Is it possible that the configure script is looking for OpenGL in a way that works on linux, but not on a mac?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that `configure` script is broken (surprise, surprise, it's [autotools](https://twitter.com/timmartin2/status/23365017839599616)). Anyway on MacOS X OpenGL comes in the form of a *Framework* and not a library. Also I don't see how the configure script could have found `GL/gl.h`, since in MacOS X the path is `OpenGL/gl.h` as found by the following line of the configure script.

Interim solution: Modify the `configure.in` file not to look for OpenGL at all and add `-framework OpenGL` in the `Makefile.in`. Long term solution: File a bug with the developers, that build configuration on on MacOS X seems to be broken.

Comment: I was able to get the configure script to run successfully with the following configure line: `./configure CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/X11/include" LDFLAGS="-framework OpenGL -L/usr/X11/lib"`

Comment: but then make fails with the following error:  `hid/common/hidgl.c:647:49: error: use of undeclared identifier '_GLUfuncptr'
  gluTessCallback(info.tobj, GLU_TESS_ERROR,   (_GLUfuncptr)myError);` so maybe GL, OpenGL is not found properly?

Comment: @James: On MacOS X **do not** use the X11 support. It requires to start programs within a X11 server (which AFAIK is no longer installed by default with the most recent MacOS X versions) and severely limits the OpenGL capabilities. You always want to use the OpenGL **framework** in MacOS X. In fact all the libraries using OpenGL I write contain some checks in their headers, that if they're compiled for MacOS X will error out if X11 is used for the same program.

Comment: @James: `-framework OpenGL` is not just a linker flag. It must be applied to the compiler as well, so that the proper header files can be found. Also you probably want to adjust any occurance of `#include <GL/glu.h>` with `#ifdef __APPLE__ #include <OpenGL/glu.h> #else #include <GL/glu.h> #endif` (similar for gl.h). Personally I consider the antics of Apple as an act of sabotage. And of course the GNU Autotools don't make the whole thing simpler.

Comment: The relevant source has: `#ifdef HAVE_OPENGL_GLU_H
    #   include <OpenGL/glu.h> 
    #else
    #   include <GL/glu.h>
    #endif`     Also, I there's no configure.in file (just a configure.ac), and I'm not sure how to modify the configure script to not look for OpenGL, or where to add `-framework OpenGL` in `Makefile.in`, but I'll look around to see if I can figure it out

Comment: FWIW, if I omit the `-L/usr/X11/lib` in the `LDFLAGS` of the `configure` call, then `configure` fails (unable to find OpenGL library).  On my machine, `/usr/X11` is a soft-link to `/opt/X11`, from an XQuartz install (not installed by default in OS X).    So with `./configure LDFLAGS="-framework OpenGL -L/usr/X11/lib"` and then adding `typedef void ( * _GLUfuncptr)();` to `src/global.h`, I was able to get `pcb` to compile.  The GUI is messed up though (perhaps due to an OpenGL vs. X11 issue as you alluded to before).

Comment: @James: Well, `configure` is producing a lot of test programs, that it tries to compile. These test programs are generated as by the ruled specified by the creator of the configure script (using the `configure.in` or `configure.ac and the `automake.*` files – automake is a complex beast). If those are testing for X11/GLX and not for MacOS X, well, you get the idea. If all you want is getting the darn thing to build you can manually edit the generated configure cache and go from there. Or you could try to replace automake completely and use something a little bit saner, like CMake or premake.